# Llenar un select en Laravel

Tags: laravel, select2

Tengo un problema al tratar de rellenar un select con datos de la BD, con laravel 5.6

En mi controlador tengo el siguiente código:

```
public function index()
{
    $roles=roleUser::pluck('id_role','nombre');

    return view('auth.register',compact('roles') );
}
```

en mi vista la tengo de esta manera

```
<select id="id_role" name="id_role" class="form-control">
       <option>------Seleccionar------</option>
       @foreach($roles as $role)
       <option value="{{ $role['id_role'] }}">{{ $role['nombre'] }}</option>
       @endforeach
</select>
```

Pero cuando renderiza no me muestra ningun dato solamente asi:

```
<select id="id_role" name="id_role" class="form-control">
     <option>------Seleccionar------</option>
     <option value=""></option>
     <option value=""></option>
     <option value=""></option>
     <option value=""></option>
     <option value=""></option>
     <option value=""></option>
     <option value=""></option>
     <option value=""></option>
 </select>
```

Comment: y por que no $role->nombre y $role->id_role, en vez de como esta?

Comment: Ya intente de esa manera pero tampoco funciona

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partimos de la base de que el modelo `roleUser` tiene datos. El problema se te genera después de utilizar el método `pluck` ([Documentación oficial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-pluck)), este método te devuelve una colección en formato clave/valor. Es decir, si tenemos los siguientes datos obtendríamos:

```
$data = collect([
    ['id_role' => '1', 'nombre' => 'usuario'],
    ['id_role' => '2', 'nombre' => 'administrador'],
]);

$roles = $data->pluck('nombre', 'id_role');

$roles->all(); // ['1' => 'usuario', '2' => 'administrador']
```

Fíjate que la forma en la que hice el pluck es la siguiente: `pluck('nombre', 'id_role')`, ya que el primer parámetro obtiene los valores y el segundo las claves a los que se los asignas. Ese es tu primer fallo, haces la asignación a la inversa.

Después, la forma correcta de imprimir un conjunto de claves/valor sería la siguiente:

```
@foreach( $roles as $key => $value )
   <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Eres un Dios fue muy util tu ayuda. Muchisimas gracias

Comment: Para eso estamos, para ayudar. Saludos!